# I scaled down a video, but the bit rate does not change

Tags: ffmpeg, scale, libx264

I have a 3000 by 3000 VR video encoded in H264. I scaled down the video by

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=2160:2160 output.mp4
```

To my surprise, the bit rate of `output.mp4` did not decrease (in fact, it increased a little bit).

Is not a scaled down video supposed to have lower bit rate than the original video? What is the mechanism of `-vf scale=***`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale filter has no effect on the encoder's bitrate control.

Yes, a scaled down video should have a lower bitrate **if** it is encoded with the same encoder settings as the source. In your command, since no encoder parameters are explicitly set, ffmpeg defaults to encoder `x264` with rate-control mode CRF with value 23. Apparently, this results in the same bitrate as the full-sized source. Set a higher value to reduce size.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=2160:2160 -crf 26 output.mp4
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Why would you have to change crf? That's "constant quality", right? This means that we should expect a lower bitrate on a down scale.

Comment: @DigiVisionMedia crf is "constant ratefactor". also, this all is searchable in the web, don't be lazy please.

Comment: Wouldn't this make a lesser quality encode?

Comment: hmm, need 50 rep to comment... so posting instead. **increase** crf to **reduce** bit rate, also reduces quality<br>
**decrease** crf to **increase** bit rate, improves quality<br>
+/- 6 crf is about half / double the bitrate (at least for x265). good intro:<br>
http://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html